# C# Wpf Datagrid Last Column Width="*" Collapses Other Columns

Tags: c#, datagrid, width

I'm using a datagrid which stretches horizontally with respect to window size.

Because of i want to get rid of extra column generated on right side, i set all of the column sizes to "Auto" except the last column. I set last column's size to "*".

Finally i got rid of extra column generated in right side.

But now, when i fill the datagrid with information all the column sizes except the last column collapses to their header widths.

Why columns have the width of their headers? I set their widths to "Auto" they should respect also their cell sizes.

Note: I don't want to set MinWidths for columns, they should automatically sized with respect to column and cell size.

Thanks..

Comment: Post the relevant XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the following code:

```
private void FitToContent()
    {
        int numCols ;
        int i ;

        numCols = dg.Columns.Count() ;
        i = 0 ;

        // where dg is your data grid's name...
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dg.Columns)
        {
            if(i < numCols - 1)
            { 
                //if you want to size ur column as per the cell content
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToCells);
                //if you want to size ur column as per the column header
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToHeader);
                //if you want to size ur column as per both header and cell content
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
            }
            else
            {
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }
            i++ ;
        }
    }
```

Make sure you keep **HorizontalScrollVisibility** to **Auto** for all columns

Comment: Yes, but i don't want the extra auto generated column.

Comment: I changed "numCols = dg.Columns.Count()" to "numCols = dg.Columns.Count()-1" , selected Auto option in if statement and deleted else statement completely. Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: And i set last column's Width="*" in Xaml file.